# confused with term "Dual Band"

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dual-band

So...I just got my new router. It's a N900 wireless router.

I was wondering what "N900" means..and found out that it means 450Mbps + 450Mbps.

The router also says it supports dual band. What's that mean exactly?

Does it mean that I can use both 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz to double my transfer speed among my computers?  My friend just told me that it's not that case. If he's right..why do companies say 450 + 450 and it's super fast because it's a dual band router?

Comment: http://compnetworking.about.com/od/wireless80211/f/dual-band-wireless.htmhttp://compnetworking.about.com/od/wireless80211/f/dual-band-wireless.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not see 900Mbls on any *one* device/client. There are two separate bands running at 450Mbps.

Technically, the router is transferring 900Mbps but it's just divided by two devices. Marketers love to make things sound fancier than they are.